# Remove "Calculate" button in the status bar in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How do I hide or remove the "Calculate" button in the status bar in Excel 2007?

I keep on accidentally clicking it when switching between sheets.

EDIT:
To clarify, the worksheet is in manual calculation and needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

This button should only appear if you have the worksheet set to "manual calculation" and you have made a recent change to the sheet contents requiring recalculation.  If you do not need this enabled, consider changing back to the default setting of "automatic calculation" in the settings menu, as per the example on [this page](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/controlling-excel-2007-formula-calculations-manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

I offer this, not as an answer to your question, but as a solution to your problem: Create an extra sheet with nothing on it.  Give it a long name and move it to the left of Sheet1. 
If you prefer, do this multiple times. 
After a few days, you will grow accustomed to clicking three inches to the right of the lower left corner when you want to switch between sheets.

[image]

Another option is simply to get into the habit of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>.